# Is there an easy way to integrate a profiling tool with Code::Blocks?

Tags: profiling, codeblocks, integrate

I love working with the [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) (C++ IDE), and I got to wondering... is there a tool you can use to profile your code that integrates with Code::Blocks?

I'm thinking of a Windows tool right now, but a Linux tool would be good too.

Maybe something like `valgrind` but for Windows.

Comment: I'm confused... you ask about profiling but you also mention valgrind. Are you trying to find memory leaks, threading bugs, or make your program run faster?

Comment: @Sam: Memory leaks. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You may wanna check the [Code::Blocks Plugins page](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code%3a%3aBlocks_Plugins) ,the "contrib" section .There are plugins for integrating Valgrind ,GProf ,etc.
On Ubuntu you have to install code blocks plugins-contrib in order to use this.
On Windows I think that you have to select the plugins that you gonna use at install time ,at least is what I do,but I am sure that there is another option.